# RequestMapping in spring with weird patterns

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have defined the controller method in spring like following

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView register(HttpSession session) {
```

and when i try to access the register page it is working fine.

```
localhost:8080/myapp/register
```

but the issue is it is giving me the same page with all these patterns

```
localhost:8080/myapp/register.htm
localhost:8080/myapp/register.abc
localhost:8080/myapp/register.pqrasdfdadf
```

i want to stop this behaviour. can anyone suggest ?

Comment: What URL pattern is your dispatcher servlet mapped to?

Comment: in web.xml everything is redirecting to spring i.e "/*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you do your Web MVC configuration, you have to set the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` [`useSuffixPatternMatch`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#setUseSuffixPatternMatch-boolean-) property to `false`.

If you're doing your configuration through a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` sub class, simply do

```
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    return mapping;
}
```

With XML configuration, you'll need to explicitly declare a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` with id `requestMappingHandlerMapping` and set the corresponding `<property>`.

This property, which is `true` by default, determines

> Whether to use suffix pattern match (`".*"`) when matching patterns to
>   requests. If enabled a method mapped to "/users" also matches to
>   `"/users.*"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use `@RequestMapping(value = "/register/", method = RequestMethod.GET)` , you can easily solve your problem.

**Another Solution:**

Use regular expression.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{varName:/register$}")
```

Here $ represents the end of the string.

Comment: Except now `localhost:8080/myapp/register` won't work.

Comment: You have to use localhost:8080/myapp/register/ for request.

Comment: Which kind of defeats the purpose of what they want. Also, what happens if you send local host:8080/myapp/register/.whatever?

Comment: It won't create problem. You can try it yourself.